# T-SQL match special characters. Pre should match Pré

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

I have a list of company names and the user has to enter his company name to get into the system. Let's say we have the company "Pré ABC", now I want the user to be able to type "Pre" or "Pré".

First I thought this was build-in functionality of the LIKE statement, but unfortunately it isn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is really funny that I read about this only few days ago and run into this question.
Good for my review on this subject ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with collation. Each database has its own collation (and any column can override that collation, too). In your case, you're looking for a collation that's not accent-sensitive, and not case-sensitive. Try configuring the database to "`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`". That decodes as "code page 1, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive", which should make your queries work as desired.

Comment: Beat me to it while I was looking up the full syntax for the collation order. This also has the advantage of being database global, so the entire system works this way.

Comment: This seems to work. I however didn't do it on the full database but on the specific comparrison with:  
table.X COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI =  
@Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  1
WHERE   N'Pré ABC' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI LIKE N'%Pre%'
```